# Uploading image file to Strapi CMS API with Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, content-management-system, guzzle, strapi

I am trying to upload a image to Strapi CMS using their API together with Laravel & Guzzle. Whenever I do a POST request, the simple data, like name, description, etc. Is perfectly getting posted, it's only the image which is not. There aren't even any errors to take action from, just "200 success".

Am I doing this wrong?

This is what I have tried:
So far my handler:

```
$this->processStrapiProductCategory([
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'ImageCover',
                    'contents' => fopen('storage/app/' . $sliderImageInternalUrl, 'r' ),
                ],
            ],
            'json' => [
                'TextCover' => $sliderText,
                'Description' => $categoryDescription,
                'Name' => $categoryName,
                'Slug' => $categorySlug,
            ],
        ]);
```

And guzzle:

```
private function processStrapiProductCategory($options): void
    {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false]);

        try {
            $response = $client->request('POST', '192.168.1.109:1337/product-categories/', $options);
            dump('StatusCode of guzzle request: ' . $response->getStatusCode());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dump('Guzzle error: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you will find when you see guzzle docs for [multipart](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#multipart)

> This option cannot be used with body, form_params, or json

Change it to below

```
[
    'multipart' => [
        [
                    'name' => 'ImageCover',
                    'contents' => fopen('storage/app/' . $sliderImageInternalUrl, 'r' ),
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'data',
            'contents' => json_encode(
                [
                   'TextCover' => $sliderText,
                   'Description' => $categoryDescription,
                   'Name' => $categoryName,
                   'Slug' => $categorySlug,
                ]
            ),
        ]
    ]
]
```